# 'Check is not defined' in client.wait_for in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, undefined

I want to read the message sent by the author after giving the command `=hi` to my discord bot. So I used this code I found online to get what the author sent:

```py
msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check) #error goes here, 'check' is not defined
await ctx.send(msg.content)
```

but the problem is the `check` is not defined when this function is run

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'check' is not defined
```

How do I fix it?
I haven't defined `check` in front this function, but how do I define `check`?

Comment: Have you defined check before this line?

Comment: Hello, may you show your code?

Comment: @MoeedAzhar No, but how?

Comment: I havent defined check in front this function, but how to defined check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check is this:

```
def check(m):
    return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel
```

Just add this inside your command function and above

`msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)`

So:

```
def check(m):
    return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel

msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
await ctx.send(msg.content)
```

Comment: Ya this answer is work for me, thank you.

Comment: No problem glad to help